# Why won't this Fragment Transaction work with view binding

Tags: android, kotlin

While I learn about fragment transaction, I tried transaction with view binding

```
supportFragmentManager.commit{
    add(binding.fragmentContainerView1, ExampleFragment::class.java, null)
```

but it didn't work.
and code below work properly

```
supportFragmentManager.commit{
    add(R.id.fragment_container_view_1, ExampleFragment::class.java, null)
```

why function add with parameter binding.fragmentContainerView1 didnt work?

I can't find a reason

plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found reason.

Using binding.fragmentContainerView1.id works well.

Function add's first parameter require id, binding.view didn't mean it's Id